# jQuery replace array of words in a string

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am trying to "highlight" specific words in a string after the string has been created.

I'm doing this currently:

```
var keywords = [
    "Monday",
    "monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "thursday",
    "Friday",
    "friday",
    "Saturday",
    "saturday",
    "Sunday",
    "sunday"
    ];    

function highlightImportant(that) {
    that.find('.email-container').each(function(){
        var full_text = $(this).text();
        $.each(keywords, function(i){
            full_text = full_text.replace(keywords[i], "<b>"+keywords[i]+"</b>");
            $(this).text(full_text);
        });
    });
}
```

this function is called at the end of this:

```
function getEmails(email, name) {
    console.log("working...");
    $('.contact--details__show__emails').empty();
    $.post('php/contacts-get-email.php', {email:email}, function(data) {
        var email_body = data.split("<:>");
        $.each(email_body.reverse(), function(i){
            if(email_body[i]) {
                var direction = email_body[i].split(':dir:')[0];
                var email_text = email_body[i].split(':dir:')[1].split(':date:')[0];
                var email_date = email_body[i].split(':dir:')[1].split(':date:')[1];
                var d = new Date(0);
                d.setUTCSeconds(email_date);
                if(direction === "TO"){
                    var initial = "Us"; 
                } else {
                    var initial = name; 
                }
                var email_block = $('<div class="emailBlock dir-'+direction+'" style="opacity:0;">\
                                    <div class="avatar">'+ initial +'</div>\
                                    <div class="email-container">'+email_text+'</div>\
                                    <div class="date">'+d+'</div>\
                                </div>');
                $('.contact--details__show__emails').append(email_block);
                email_block.delay(100*i).animate({"opacity":"1"}, 500);
                highlightImportant($('.contact--details__show__emails'));
            }
        }); 
    }); 
}
```

This seems like it should work, and when I `console.log` the event, I see it running through each keyword for every container, but it seems it's not finding the keywords even when they exist.

What I'd like to see happen is when I have a string like this:

```
var string = "Let's meet Monday or Tuesday";
```

I'd like to have them turn bold, like so:

"Let's meet **Monday** or **Tuesday**"

Any thoughts?

Comment: Strings are immutable hence `.replace(...)` returns a new string -> `full_text = full_text.replace(...)`

Comment: Oh, so I need to make it a variable, then replace the text...

Comment: can you should the html and js that eventually calls highlightImportant?

Comment: ideally put it all in a jsFiddle so we can try it ourselves

Comment: @gabriel, I will try.  Unfortunately, there's an AJAX call that I won't be able to simulate, but I'll work something out

Comment: only put the minimum amount of code to replicate the issue, don't need anything there that won't cause the issue

Comment: Move `$(this).text(full_text)` in the inner `$.each()` out of it. `this` at this place isn't an `.email-container` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors in this line:

```
$(this).text(full_text);
```

1) `this` points to string rather to DOM element and 2) you should use `html()` method if you want markup to go into element.

And `String.replace()` in that form you use will replace only first entry, so you should do this:

```
that.find('.email-container').each(function(){
        var full_text = $(this).text();
        $.each(keywords, function(i) {
            full_text = full_text.replace(new RegExp(keywords[i],"gi"), "<b>"+keywords[i]+"</b>");
        });
        $(this).html(full_text);
    });
```

Comment: Accepted answer for the information on `.replace()` and the fix using regex.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Two problems. First of all your `$(this)` in your `$.each` loop is not the DOM-Element!
Second problem: you use `$(this).text(full_text)` but you want to set `....html(full_text)`. You are using html tags to highlight the words (`<b>`) which would be removed if you use `text`

```js
var keywords = [
    "Monday",
    "monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "thursday",
    "Friday",
    "friday",
    "Saturday",
    "saturday",
    "Sunday",
    "sunday"
    ];    
function highlightImportant(that) {
    that.find('.email-container').each(function(){
        var full_text = $(this).html(),
            element = $(this);
        $.each(keywords, function(i){
            full_text = full_text.replace(keywords[i], "<b>"+keywords[i]+"</b>");
        });
        element.html(full_text);
    });
}

highlightImportant($("#container"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div class="email-container">Let's meet Monday or Tuesday</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Move the `element.html(full_text)` out of the `$.each()`. There's no need to update the content for each keyword separately.

Comment: Wow, I must be tired. What simple mistakes!! Thank you, I will try this out shortly when I get a chance and report back

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution:

```js
var string = "Let's meet Monday or Tuesday";

function highlightKeyword(string) {
  return string.replace(/(Monday|monday|Tuesday|tuesday|Wednesday|wednesday|Thursday|thursday|Friday|friday|Saturday|saturday|Sunday|sunday)/g, "<strong>$&</strong>");
}

$('p').html(highlightKeyword(string));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Yes, simple, though I will be using more words than just the days of the week.  I'm sorry I didn't mention that!