# Replace all occurrences of an array of words in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to highlight all occurrences of an array of words anywhere on the page, regardless of their parent element.

I've adapted the following [question's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746807/jquery-replace-array-of-words-in-a-string) and it works great if I know the selector to use the function on. However, the words could appear in ANY selector, so I'm trying to use a wildcard selector, but it's not working.

```
(function($) {
var keywords = ['Breathalyzer', 'Marijuana', 'Alcohol'];

function highlightWords(element) {
    full_text = element.html();
    $.each(keywords, function(i) {
        full_text = full_text.replace(RegExp(keywords[i], "gi"), "<span class='highlighttext'>"+keywords[i]+"</span>");
    });
    element.html(full_text);
  }
highlightWords($("*"));

})(jQuery);
```

I'm using a regexp that's case insensitive so that it matches the search terms regardless of case. And I'm expecting the function to wrap all matched terms in `<span class="highlighttext"></span>` but it's not working...

**EDIT:** I guess I should add that I'm not getting any sort of errors in the console

Comment: You don't need to select all elements. Just the top level element will do. The problem with this approach though is that it causes a reflow for the entire document, _and_ it replaces words that are not text content, for example an attribute name or value, or even code in inline CSS / JavaScript will be modified. This is not a very robust approach.

Comment: Works fine for me as-is https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tyu087nr/2/

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't thought of that @PatrickRoberts... Any suggestions on how to improve the code to be more specific and less resource intensive so I can refactor accordingly?

Comment: @j08691 strange... It's not working for me on the page itself. But it does appear to be working in your jsfiddle. Maybe there's something else at play on the page that's causing it to break? I guess I'll dig deeper. Thanks!

Comment: Be sure to test this type functionality with a set of words like "test a class using my label of words within my span of time and highlight them in good form and style"

Comment: Beware of `full_text = element.html();` and  `full_text` that it has scope outside the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer:

There are a few things that need to be changed for this to work as you'd expect:

1. `$("*")` returns a collection. It's an array of elements, not a single element. Therefore passing the array into a function expecting a single element will not work.

**Solution:**

We can fix the above by using JQuery's `.each` function to iterate over each item in the collection and *then* calling your highlight function.

---

2. We have to adjust your `highlightWords` function to be on the receiving end of the `each` method.

**Solution:**

We change the parameters to match what's passed
   in. This is why instead of `element`, we use `index, element`.

---

3. `.html` is a JQuery method. We need to be sure that the `element` variable that we receive **contains** this method or we won't be able to use it.

**Solution:**

Since the `element` is not a JQuery object, we wrap the element within a JQuery object by passing the `element` variable in as a selector. `element = $(element);`

---

### Working Code:

```js
(function($) {
var keywords = ['Breathalyzer', 'Marijuana', 'Alcohol'];

function highlightWords(index, element) {
    element = $(element);
    full_text = element.html();
    $.each(keywords, function(i) {
        full_text = full_text.replace(RegExp(keywords[i], "gi"), "<span class='highlighttext'>"+keywords[i]+"</span>");
    });
    element.html(full_text);
  }
$("*").each(highlightWords);

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.highlighttext {
 color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<p>Hello Alcohol</p>
<p>This is a test of <code>marijuana</code></p>
<small>Maybe we should get a Breathalyzer?</small>
<h3>No, no, we should get more Alcohol.</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Not that it would be likely with this particular group of words, but just humor me. Add an attribute `data-alcohol="foo"` to the `<p>` tag and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation of what I was doing wrong. It's nice to learn new things every day!

Comment: I see what you're saying now @PatrickRoberts... It's probably not the best solution, but I just added multiple calls to text elements `$('p').each(highlightWords);` and then `$('h1').each(highlightWords);` etc.